# ffmpeg adds black line between stacked videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following command to stack two videos.

```
ffmpeg -i video_1.mp4 -i video_2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:500,pad='iw+mod(iw\,2)':'ih+mod(ih\,2)'[v0];[v0][1:v]hstack=inputs=2" output.mp4
```

Not sure if this matters, but video_1.mp4 is static, as I created it from a .png, and is much shorter than video_2.mp4. So when I execute the following command, ffmpeg duplicates frames, indicated by the "More than 1000 frames duplicated" message.

My issue is that the resulting video has a vertical black line between the two videos (between the illustration on the left and the "joint angles" on the right).

[image]

This vertical line is not there if I stack video_1.mp4 or video_2.mp4 to itself.

I have no idea what is going on. Could someone help?

Comment: Why the padding?

Comment: One of the videos has a height with an odd number of pixels. So ffmpeg complained that it was not divisible by 2.

Comment: Don't pad the width, only the height.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how I could do this, i.e. padding only the height?

Comment: @Gyan if I try to remove the width-padding by changing to ffmpeg -i video_1.mp4 -i video_2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:500,pad='iw':'ih+mod(ih\,2)'[v0];[v0][1:v]hstack=inputs=2" output.mp4 I get "Input area 0:0:325:500 not within the padded area 0:0:324:500 or zero-sized"

Comment: Also change the -1 in scale to -2